# How to add elements to an array in Scala, and find variable type?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have the below block of Scala code as part of my data processing pipeline. Form what I understand so far, the UDF takes in one argument `file_contents` which is of type `String` type. The UDF then does a bunch of string processing, including a `split`.

The code works without any errors, but I'm trying to edit in the following way and struggling, mostly due to my inexperience with Scala, and the difficulty in finding answers online.

- I want to be able 2 empty strings and 2 zeros to `info` based on the length of `info`. If the length of `info` is 28, then add these four values, else continue. How can I accomplish this in the below code? I want to add this code before `val param_data`.

I also have the following questions about this code if someone doesn't mind answering.

1. If the `split` converts the string to an Array, why am I not able to print the length of it using `println(info)`? This line instead seems to be printing a very large number which I believe is the summed length of all the strings.
2. How do you know what is being returned by this UDF? I don't see a `return` statement like in Python, etc.

   ```
   def extract_FileContent_test = udf((file_contents: String) => {

      val info = (file_contents.replace("\",\"", "     ")
       .replace("\"", "")
       .replaceAll("    ", "|")
       .replaceAll(" : \r\n", " : empty\r\n")
       .replaceAll("\r\n", "|")
       .replaceAll(" : ", "|")
       .replaceAll(": ", "|")
       .split("\\|")
       .map(x => x.trim.replaceAll(" -", ""))
       .filterNot(s => s == ""))
      println(info.length)
      // type info : Array[String]

      // type sec_index : Array[Int]
      val sec_index = info.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1.startsWith("---")).map(_._2)

      if (sec_index.length > 2) {

      // parse meta_data (beam tuning context) and param_data (beam tuning parameter) separately

      val meta_data = (info.slice(0, sec_index(0)).toList.grouped(2)
       .filter(l => l.length == 2)
       .filter(l => l(1) != "Start" & l(1) != "")
       .map { case List(a, b) => b }
       .toArray.mkString(",")
       )

      // println(meta_data)

      val param_data = (info.slice(sec_index(0) + 1, sec_index(1)).toList.grouped(3)
       .filter(l => l.length == 3)
       .filter { case List(a, b, c) => Try(c.split(" ")(0).toDouble).isSuccess }
       .map { case List(a, b, c) => Array(a, c.split(" ")(0)).mkString(",") }
       .toArray)
      // println(param_data)

      /* one meta data will have > 100 param
      so besides meta columns, we add 2 columns for param_name, param_value
      */
      param_data.map(meta_data + "," + _)
      }
      else {
      Array[String]()
      }
      })
   ```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to add to the code?

Comment: I want to be able 2 empty strings and 2 zeros to the `info` array (if it's an array) based on the length of `info`. If the length of `info` is 28, then add these four values, else continue.

Answer (score 0):

1. to get the length of info use info.length
2. in Scala the last statement is the return value - here it is the  `if (sec_index.length > 2)` so it either returns an empty array of Strings or the params_data after the last map

regarding adding data to info you can do something like

```
val info_with_filler =  if ( info.length<28) info ++  List("","" ,"0","0") else info
```

and then use info_with_filler later in the code instead of info

Comment: Thanks, but like I said in my question, `println(info.length)` is printing a very large number which I believe is the summed length of all the strings, instead of the actual length of the array.

Comment: in the question, you print(info) (which gives the type and the handle) info.size or info.length will give you the number of items in the array/list

Comment: Sorry I corrected it now. Both `info.length` and `info.size` give the same answer, i.e. 768, whereas I'm pretty sure the expected length of my array is <50.

Comment: that's the length. You can check what string you get before the split (cut this into two lines) and verify

Comment: Sorry I'm confused-isn't `info` a string before the split? 
I tried using `.toArray.mkString(",")` by running the following,

`val info = (file_contents.replace("\",\"", "     ")
        .replace("\"", "")
        .replaceAll("    ", "|")
        .replaceAll(" : \r\n", " : empty\r\n")
        .replaceAll("\r\n", "|")
        .replaceAll(" : ", "|")
        .replaceAll(": ", "|")
        .split("\\|")
        .map(x => x.trim.replaceAll(" -", ""))
        .filterNot(s => s == ""))
        .toArray.mkString(",")
    println(info.length)`

But the result is even higher `13158`

Comment: Sorry for that code mess. I have put the code in the following fiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/RHqwLbH/1.

Comment: of course - now "length" is the size of the string. What I meant is you can look  at the string and verify it indeed has more than 50 terms separated by "|" if you print/look at it before the split https://scalafiddle.io/sf/YnFyeeA/0